# Get the list of records to which a file is Attached

Tags: netsuite

I want to get the list of all the records(whether it may be entity record, transaction record or any other record) to which a single file is attached from the file cabinet in Netsuite. Is there any way to do so??

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: I have tried to create a saved search and pass the file internal id in criteria and get the columns. But there were no such columns on Document search to get all the record types. So, is there any other way you could suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the saved search approach is the best way.  But I don't think you can do it by creating a Document saved search.  I think you have to create an entity saved search, a transaction saved search, etc, and then put in the file ID into the criteria filter's "File fields..." internal ID field.

Having to create a saved search for each record type is a bit clunky, but if you have SuiteScript experience it helps if you have the "NetSuite: Search Export" chrome extension.  You can create one saved search on the front-end and then use that extension to "Export as script" the one saved search and try to reproduce its criteria for each record type that you are interested in linking to the one file.

Comment: Also if you can't immediately find "File fields..." criteria, make sure you scroll close to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you want to search a file for a Salesorder. You need to do it separate for entity, transaction etc, remove type and id for all records search.
Here is an example in 2.0.

```
var salesorderSearchObj = search.create({
    type: "salesorder",
    filters:
    [
        ["type","anyof","SalesOrd"], 
        "AND", 
        ["internalid","anyof",12345], 
        "AND", 
        ["taxline","is","F"], 
        "AND", 
        ["cogs","is","F"], 
        "AND", 
        ["shipping","is","F"], 
        "AND", 
        ["mainline","is","T"]
    ],
    columns:
    [
        search.createColumn({
            name: "trandate",
            sort: search.Sort.ASC,
            label: "Date"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "internalid",
            join: "file",
            label: "Internal ID"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "url",
            join: "file",
            label: "URL"
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: "url",
            join: "lineFile",
            label: "URL"
        })
    ]
});
var searchResultCount = salesorderSearchObj.runPaged().count;
salesorderSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
    var fileId = result.getValue({
        name: "internalid",
        join: "file",
        label: "Internal ID"
    });

    var fileObj = file.load({id: fileId});
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I went into a new search, select transaction.  When that comes up, click on personalize search and go to the results tab. Go to the bottom of the list of columns and  (you probably want to remove some of the other columns as well, but I recommend you preview the search first to see which ones you can remove).  In the new column, select "File Fields..." and in the pop-up box, select Name.  I also went to the filters field and by type put a checkmark in the box to show it on the search.  Name your search and view the results.  You can then sort by the document number to see all attachments, the vendor name, or even search by the attached file name to find out what transaction it was attached to.  Hope this helps!